# Hadoop hdfs showing ls: `/home/hduser/input/': No such file or directory error

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, hadoop

I have installed **Hadoop 2.6** on single machine using [this tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html). I am using Ubuntu 12.04 machine and Java version 1.6.0_27.

I have created separate user as **hduser** for Hadoop operations.
I have set **HADOOP_HOME** envrioment variable's value **/usr/local/hadoop** where I have extracted the Hadoop distribution.

Now I am following an [**example**](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html). But when I execute the command `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfs -ls /home/hduser/input/` it gives following error -

> 15/01/02 18:32:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
> ls: `/home/hduser/input/': No such file or directory

Also I have tried command:
`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /home/hduser/input/`, but still getting same error.

When I run the command `jps` it shows -

```
16023 SecondaryNameNode
16200 ResourceManager
16432 NodeManager
18971 Jps
15503 NameNode
```

It is not showing any process for **JobTracker** and  **TaskTracker**.

How can I resolve this error and to start/list the process for **JobTracker** and  **TaskTracker**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access you local directory using hdfs. Try following steps:

```
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH ##Make this entry in your ~/.bashrc file
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hduser
hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/hduser/input
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hduser/input
echo "Hello World" > file01
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /user/hduser/input
hadoop fs -cat /user/hduser/input/file01
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply. I have followed above steps it executed successfully. But when I give command **hdfs dfs -cat /user/hduser/input/file01**, it show error **cat: `/user/hduser/input/file01': No such file or directory**

Comment: You need to create the file first or copy from your local file system to hdfs and then read it. I have edited the answer to take care of the same.

Comment: Ohk. Got it. I followed your steps. I think you missed source file name "file01" in -copyFromLocal command. Your steps are working. But  I got **DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/hduser/input/file01._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation** error. 
Thanks for your response

Comment: Your datanode is down which is fine for now.

Comment: Yes like I already mentioned in question that there are  no processes running for Jobtracker and Tasktracker. I am looking on it.