# copyFromLocal: `/user/hduser/input': No such file or directory

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

I was trying to do WordCount tutorial from this [website](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v2.0) but was having some problems and I followed the solutions from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742858/hadoop-hdfs-showing-ls-home-hduser-input-no-such-file-or-directory-error). It was all fine until I tried to execute `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /user/hduser/input` which produced this error

```
copyFromLocal: `/user/hduser/input': No such file or directory
```

And I tried to double confirm if  there is such file by executing `hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hduser/input` and it says `mkdir:`/user/hduser/input': File exists`

So I am a little bit confused on where went wrong. I just wanna able to execute the copyFromLocal function.

```
When I run the command jps it shows - 
16023 SecondaryNameNode
16200 ResourceManager
16432 NodeManager
18971 Jps
15503 NameNode
```

Comment: hadoop fs -copyFromLocal  localdirectory hdfsdirectory - this is the actual syntax... Please check

Comment: I tried hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /Desktop/file01 /user/hduser/input

but still it says copyFromLocal: `/Desktop/file01': No such file or directory

Comment: @madhu I got it. Thanks mate. God bless you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /user/hduser/directory_in_local_fs /user/hduser/directory_in_hadoop_fs
```

copied directory_in_local_fs (local file or dicectory) into directory_in_hadoop_fs (path hadoop file system)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create directory before copying.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hduser/directory_in_hadoop_fs
```